# not able to return Json from controller on jsonp request cross domain

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonp

I am having a requirement to invoke an action returning Json data on another project from my MVC project (assuming cross origin), Using ajax.
Ajax function

```
            var url1 = 'http://localhost:55308/Reports?type=E&code=1200?callback=?";                          


            $.ajax({                    
                url: url1,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                success: function (response) {
                    data = JSON.parse(response); 

                    alert('sucess');

                },
                error: function(xhr,status, error) { alert('error' + error.message);  }
            });
```

It is invoking the controller but returning error :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`{"result1":"abc"}`

Controller in another project is like below:

```
  [AllowAnonymous]        
    public ActionResult Reports(int Code, string type,string callback=null){
--- processing data--(which is working fine)
generatedPath = "df";
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    sb.Append(callback + "(");
                    sb.Append(js.Serialize(generatedPath));
                    sb.Append(");");
 return Json(sb, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Returning Json result. Should I encapsulate Json to JSONP data in ajax request.
Stuck on this for two days and help on google is not helping.
Please appreciate help. Please
TIA

Edited : Added callback to jsonp request.Also dataserialized which gives me ({"df"}). Is this right?

Comment: You need to send a JSONP response from the controller, not JSON.

Comment: Can you change the controller to send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, so you don't need to use JSONP?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.. Please any help or link?

Comment: Thanks.. But now its giving me this error jQuery1830874713271856308_1456967043972 was not called no matter if its executed

Comment: Sounds like you're not putting the callback name into the response correctly.

Comment: Edited question with the code changes done. Pls have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105207/discussion-between-user-rhee-and-barmar).

Comment: I don't know asp.net, I can't help you any further.

Comment: Thanks for the help though.. Looks like I ma stuck. Anyone Please